# How to disable Always on Visible Workspace

Tags: workspaces

On my desktop one window on left side is open and there is a check on Always on Visible Workspace.

How do I disable that?

Comment: Right click on the window's top panel and uncheck that option

Answer (score 1):

As [Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy](https://askubuntu.com/users/295286/sergiy-kolodyazhnyy) said, "Right click on the window's top panel and uncheck that option".
However, if you have used some [automated means](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1278440) to make that option the default, you will have modify that.

Comment: Someway to do this via command line?